# No delegate, didFailToReceiveAdWithError

Tags: swift

i have this code:

```
class ViewControllergame: UIViewController, ADBannerViewDelegate {

 var bannerView:ADBannerView!

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.canDisplayBannerAds = true
    bannerView?.delegate = self

    bannerView?.hidden = true
 }

     func bannerViewDidLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!) {

    bannerView?.hidden = false
}



func bannerViewActionShouldBegin(banner: ADBannerView!, willLeaveApplication willLeave: Bool) -> Bool {
    return willLeave
}

func bannerView(banner: ADBannerView!, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: NSError!) {
    bannerView?.hidden = true

}

}
```

But it goes not in the didFailToReceiveAdWithError, when my app goes in standby i get this error:

```
ADBannerView: Unhandled error (no delegate or delegate does not implement didFailToReceiveAdWithError:): Error Domain=ADErrorDomain Code=1 "Service session terminated.
```

How can i fix this?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. Could you provide some information like which XCode version?

Comment: @chuck xcode version 6.3.2, is my code right than?

Comment: @da1lbi3 How is you initialized your bannerView?

Comment: I testet your code and deployed in an iPad Mini with iOS 8.3. It works for me, but the delegate method is never thrown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you've implemented the methods but they're never called because your banner delegate is not set. If you're using storyboards just

> Control-Drag

from your ADBannerView to the same ViewController where the banner is and then select "delegate" Outlet.

[image: Control-Drag]

[image: select "delegate" Outlet]